# ASP.NET event is invoked but throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

This is what my `LoginControl` class looks like:

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class LoginControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler ButtonLoginClick;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonLoginClick(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

On the page on which I am using the control, I have the following code:

```
<myComps:LoginControl runat="server" ID="LoginControl" ButtonLoginClick="btnLogin_Click"></myComps:LoginControl>
```

When I click on the login button, the event is not fired because I receive the following error

> An object is not instantiated.

I guess it is speaking of the event. The error happens exactly when I invoke the event `ButtonLoginClick`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But ho I do that properly? I tried in page_load: ButtonLoginClick = new EventHandler(); but it needs more parameters

Comment: is there a typo? btnLogin_click and btnLogin_click1

Answer (score 0):

On the page you need to change `ButtonLoginClick="btnLogin_Click"` to `OnButtonLoginClick="btnLogin_Click"`.

Then asp.net will bind your handler to the `LoginControl` event.